# move_uploaded_file(/test.txt.part1): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, mysql

I recently transfer the php files from PHP 5 to PHP 7.3. All the code works on the older server. Now, on the upload page, I keep getting this errors when trying to upload test.txt:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: temp_dir in <b>/var/www/html/wordpress/uas_tools/upload_raw/Resources/PHP/Upload.php</b> on line <b>258</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: temp_dir in <b>/var/www/html/wordpress/uas_tools/upload_raw/Resources/PHP/Upload.php</b> on line <b>261</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: temp_dir in <b>/var/www/html/wordpress/uas_tools/upload_raw/Resources/PHP/Upload.php</b> on line <b>262</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mkdir(): Invalid path in <b>/var/www/html/wordpress/uas_tools/upload_raw/Resources/PHP/Upload.php</b> on line <b>262</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file(/test.txt.part1): failed to open stream: Permission denied in <b>/var/www/html/wordpress/uas_tools/upload_raw/Resources/PHP/Upload.php</b> on line <b>266</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phppXfFAn' to '/test.txt.part1' in <b>/var/www/html/wordpress/uas_tools/upload_raw/Resources/PHP/Upload.php</b> on line <b>266</b><br />
24.09.2020: Error saving (move_uploaded_file) chunk 1 for file test.txt
```

I still have to fixing the SQL injections. Other than that, why do I keep getting the error and how could I fix it?

var_dump($result);

```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(13)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(0)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

var_dump($product);

```
NULL
```

var_dump($identifier);

```
string(9) "4-testtxt"
```

Code:

```
// loop through files and move the chunks to a temporarily created directory
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $file) {

    // check the error status
        if ($file['error'] != 0) {
            _log('error '.$file['error'].' in file '.$_GET['resumableFilename']);
            continue;
        }

        $con = SetDBConnection();
        $fileNameParts = pathinfo($_GET['resumableFilename']);
        $fileName = FormatFileName($fileNameParts["filename"]).".".$fileNameParts["extension"];

        // init the destination file (format <filename.ext>.part<#chunk>
        // the file is stored in a temporary directory
        if (isset($_GET['resumableIdentifier']) && trim($_GET['resumableIdentifier'])!='') {
            $identifier = $_GET['resumableIdentifier'];
            //var_dump($identifier);
            $sql =  "select * from raw_data_upload_status where Identifier = '$identifier'";

            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            //var_dump($result);
            $product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            //var_dump($product);// is NULL
            if ($product) {
                $temp_dir = $product["TempFolder"];
                //$temp_dir = "/var/www/html/temp";
                $dest_dir = $product["UploadFolder"];
            }
        }
        $dest_file = $temp_dir."/".$fileName.'.part'.$_GET['resumableChunkNumber'];

        // create the temporary directory
        if (!is_dir($temp_dir)) {
            mkdir($temp_dir, 0777, true);
        }

        // move the temporary file
        if (!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $dest_file)) {
            _log('Error saving (move_uploaded_file) chunk '.$_GET['resumableChunkNumber'].' for file '.$_GET['resumableFilename']);
        } else {
            _log($dest_dir);

            CreateFileFromChunks($temp_dir, $dest_dir, $fileName, $_GET['resumableChunkSize'], $_GET['resumableTotalSize'], $_GET['resumableTotalChunks'], $_GET['resumableIdentifier']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note the repeated `Undefined variable: temp_dir`. Perhaps fix that. It looks like it has no default value and is only ever declared two `if` statements deep.

Comment: Hi @Sammitch What solution do you suggest to fix that?

Comment: Debugging your code.

Comment: @Sammitch I understand that is what I need to do and clearly I can't figure it out now, but why would it work on an older server and not on a newer one?